# Is it possible to make a series read a separately defined set of values?

Tags: plotting, summation

I would like to plot a function with a sum in it. Here is the function:

$$v(k) = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{v_E \cdot m_j \cdot c}{m_j(1-c)+\sum_{i=j+1}^n m_i} $$

As you can see, the problem is that I have a set of $m_i$ ($m_1 = 12, m_2=35...$) and now I set them manually. If I want to change the set or add new masses, I also have to do it manually.

Is there a way to define this set separately and then make the series "read" the elements of this set?

Comment: why not make a function, and pass it the the maximum summation index `k` and `n` needed and the set `m` and `v`  and also `c` ?

Comment: @Nasser How do I define the set m? How do I make the sum find the appropriate value for m matching the index?

Comment: The set `m` is just a list, right?  This is the input you have, right?  If you give a small example of your data `v` and `m` it helps.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, the set of m-s is just a list and it is the input. m has to contain arbitrary real values (m stands for masses) and the output is velocities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation. See if I have understood your notation and goal:

```
ClearAll[v]
v[mList_, k_] := 
 vE c Sum[mList[[j]] / (mList[[j]] (1 - c) + Total@mList[[j ;;]]), {j, 1, k}]
```

I assumed that vE and c are constants, and I gave them some arbitraty value; similarly, let's choose an arbitrary list of masses:

```
c = 0.5;
vE = 32;
mlist = {1, 45, 12, 35};

v[mlist, 4]
(* Out: 20.7486 *)
```

Let's plot it for a range of k:

```
Plot[v[{12, 45, 30, 35}, k], {k, 0, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
m = {12, 35, 48};ve = 12;mj = 14;c = 14;numofmasses = Length[m];tot = 0;
For[a2 = 1, a2 < numofmasses + 1, a2 = a2 + 1,
an[a2] = ve*Part[m, a2]*c/(Part[m, a2]*(1 - c) + Total[m[[a2 + 1 ;; numofmasses]]]);

tot = an[a2] + tot;
];
Print[tot]
```

Put your values for the variables and it will read along the masses

Comment: be honest it was the plot